# How to select and display rows with multiple columns in a checkedlistbox with SQLCE?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, checkedlistbox

I've been following tutorials to select rows from a table and display it in a checkedListbox. This works fine with only one column. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do this while selecting multiple columns. Google isn't very helpful either.

I need to display all articles, from a stock. Together with it's unique ID. So that the user can check the items he needs to delete.

My code is completely messed up now, and can't even figure it out myself. Would appreciate if someone could explain it, or point me to an article/tutorial on this subject.

This is what I currently have, but as said; it's quite messed up:

```
string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database;

        string selectString = "select artikelnummer, omschrijving from Artikels";

        SqlCeDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand(selectString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string dataTableName = "Artikels";

                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, dataTableName);

                DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[dataTableName];

                foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    listboxGeselecteerd.Items.Add(dataRow);
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post part of your code it might help?

Comment: the question is "why?". Why you need to use a checkedlistbox with multiples columns. explain with more details your question.

Comment: @Rafael: Edited to add "I need to display an article, from a stock. Together with it's unique ID."

Comment: then you have multiple columns as PK ?, if your answer is yes please post in your question a tiny example of your data, showing only that we need to do to understand 100% your problem

Comment: @Rafael: Nope, I have the ID as a PK, and the name of the item is a regular column.